# PHPMailer authentication issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong or whats going on, but I'm completely confused on whats happening.  Some reason the exact same login information I'm passing for the pop->Authorise is being rejected on the SMTP level?

Here is my connection code

```
$username = 'matt@mydomain.com';
$password = 'mypass';
$server = 'mail.mydomain.com';

$pop = new POP3();
$pop->Authorise($server, 110, 30, $username, $password, 1);


$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output
echo "starting mailer..<br/>";
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = $server;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $username;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $password;                           // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('matt@mydomain.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Here is the results...

```
Server -> Client: +OK POP3 server ready <836f3c81-e565-4afd-9a31-4517bd9d6ce4@m04.internetmailserver.net> Server -> Client: +OK User:'matt@surefiretaxes.com' ok Server -> Client: +OK Password ok
```

the above shows that it was clearly accepted using POP login

```
2016-02-12 16:38:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-a2ls11.hosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Fri, 12 Feb 2016 11:38:05 -0500 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2016-02-12 16:38:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
2016-02-12 16:38:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-a2ls11.hosting.com Hello a2ls11.hosting.com [75.98.175.122] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP
2016-02-12 16:38:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-02-12 16:38:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2016-02-12 16:38:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
2016-02-12 16:38:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-a2ls11.hosting.com Hello a2ls11.hosting.com [75.98.175.122] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP
2016-02-12 16:38:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2016-02-12 16:38:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2016-02-12 16:38:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx
2016-02-12 16:38:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2016-02-12 16:38:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: yyy
2016-02-12 16:38:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2016-02-12 16:38:11 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2016-02-12 16:38:11 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-02-12 16:38:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-12 16:38:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 a2ls11.hosting.com closing connection
2016-02-12 16:38:11 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I mean what am I doing wrong?  I just can't for the life of me understand.  I even tried with and without SMTPSecure.  I tried port 25 instead of 587, however the port 587 is exact same port I use in outlook.  I'm stumped.

Comment: you login credentials are embedded in that dump as base64 strings. you'd better go change your password **IMMEDIATELY**.

Comment: oops lol thanks for heads up

Comment: but hey, at least your password (wasn't) "hunter42" or "password"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is because the host I have it on actually doesn't allow the connections to external SMTP servers.  The crazy thing is that I don't get an error from the log as shown above, it acts like the login information is incorrect.  I verified this is the case by uploading this information on another server completely and it works fine.

Comment: This is covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide where it mentions that you should check that you're actually connecting to the server you think you are.